# exec tee to redirect file will create bash process

Tags: linux, shell

the script like this :

```
exec &> >(tee -a ./test_tee.log)
ping $1
```

when the script is running in bash 7603, the exec line will create a process which name is 13069.
such as the follow:

```
root     13068  7603  0 17:15 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
root     13069 13068  0 17:15 pts/5    00:00:00 bash // where does it come from
root     13070 13068  0 17:15 pts/5    00:00:00 ping google.com
root     13071 13069  0 17:15 pts/5    00:00:00 tee -a ./test_tee.log
```

I run the script in pid 7603 bash, pid 13068 is the script, why is there pid 13069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional process is a subshell executing `tee -a ./test_tee.log`. Confirm this with `pstree -p | grep -B 1 '[t]ee'`.

You can tell this subshell to *replace* itself with `tee`. Change the relevant line to:

```
exec &> >(exec tee -a ./test_tee.log)
```

Comment: thakns. it worked. if I use  exec &> >(exec tee -a ./test_tee.log)   and then use exec ping $1. the ping will be parent process of tee.  the reason is that tee replace subbash, and ping replace bash?

Comment: @LiMingjian Yes.

Comment: I accepted it, but I am sorry for voteing asnwer because of my low reputation

Comment: @LiMingjian No need to be sorry. I know how it works.